# Instagram API returns "500 Server Error" – IP banned?

Tags: api, instagram

I'm using the official Ruby gem to request the Instagram API (GET users/xx/media/recent). After a bug in my code led to every visiter to my site requesting the API, I suspect I'm a victim of IP banning and/or Rate Limit throttling. Now all of my requests with curl return a "500 server error" response. The Ruby gem returns "Something is technically wrong".

I am surprised by this behaviour because:

- I didn't exceed the Rate limit by much since my site has few users. I estimate I did around 1-2 requests per second for a few weeks, until the bug in my code was detected. (The Rate limit is 5000 reqs/hour according to Instagram.)
- I fixed the bug about two weeks ago, and have since cached the results from Instagram for long periods. I now make 120 requests per hour at most. I would expect the IP ban to be lifted after a period of time.

Have anyone else become victim of this issue, and resolved it in some way? I have posted a bug report through the developer pages at instagram.com, but expect no answer from them.

I should add that changing client_id doesn't make any difference, and using my production client_id locally works fine.

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same problem. It also work locally. I tried to use the --interface {IP} option with the different IP's configured on my server, nothing seems to help. No reply from instagram support (mail, twitter, facebook).

Comment: Also receiving this error suddenly. Can you elaborate on caching results from instagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait and see : http://developers.instagram.com/post/82701625883/api-returning-500-errors-on-specific-ip

They know the problem.

Best regards,

Comment: You changed something? for me it still does not work.